# Fetch stock data after yahoo finace api was discontinued using C#

Tags: c#, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to fetch stock data the new way using cookie and crumb, but I can't get it to work.

```
Stream data;
StreamReader reader;
String html;
WebClient webClient;
String url;

webClient = new WebClient();
url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{0}?period1={1}&period2={2}&interval=1d&events={3}&crumb={4}";
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11");
data = webClient.OpenRead("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC");
reader = new StreamReader (data);
String crumbPattern = "\"CrumbStore\":{\"crumb\":\"(?<crumb>[^\"]+)\"}";
html = reader.ReadToEnd();
Match mCrumb = Regex.Match(html, crumbPattern);
currentCrumb = mCrumb.Value.Substring(24, mCrumb.Value.Length - 26);

int tmpS = 1494817200;
int tmpE = 1498928400;
data = webClient.OpenRead(String.Format(url, "O", tmpS, tmpE, "history", currentCrumb));
reader = new StreamReader (data);
html = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

But this does not work, when I run this I get an Unauthorized exception.

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Can anyone see that I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you setting the cookies or credential tokens for your API calls?

Comment: I have tried a couple of ways, they idea was that the webclient would handle that since the cookie is retrived by the first request. 
But I have also tried to add it to the header from the responsheaders, webClient.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", webClient.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"]);

Comment: `Set-Cookie` is the directive sent by server to **set** the cookies, not the header sent by the client! Correct header is `Cookie`, see [Mozilla - Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the currentCrumb you are retrieving is not complete.  It's truncating off the first character.  This works for me.

```
        Stream data;
        StreamReader reader;
        String html;
        WebClient webClient;
        String url;

        webClient = new WebClient();
        url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{0}?period1={1}&period2={2}&interval=1d&events={3}&crumb={4}";
        webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11");
        data = webClient.OpenRead("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC");

        string cookie = webClient.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"];

        reader = new StreamReader(data);
        String crumbPattern = "\"CrumbStore\":{\"crumb\":\"(?<crumb>[^\"]+)\"}";
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Match mCrumb = Regex.Match(html, crumbPattern);
        string[] strs = mCrumb.Value.Split(':');
        string currentCrumb = strs[2].Substring(1, strs[2].Length - 3);

        int tmpS = 1494817200;
        int tmpE = 1498928400;
        webClient.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);
        data = webClient.OpenRead(String.Format(url, "O", tmpS, tmpE, "history", currentCrumb));
        reader = new StreamReader(data);
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not properly setting the cookies for the session. You are rejected because the service cannot find the credentials for its use.

You said in comments that you tried:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", webClient.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"]);
```

But this is invalid: the `Set-Cookie` directive is sent by the server, it should not be sent in the queries by the client. Instead try:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("Cookie", webClient.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"]);
```

More on `Set-Cookie`: [HTTP Cookies - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

If that does not work, maybe you should review the documentation at [Authentication at Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/auth/) unfortunately the links provided for OAuth and OpenID are going to 404...

The Yahoo boat is sinking... Can't help you more.

Comment: I tried and it still gives me Unauthorized im affraid.